# How does Heroku use AWS S3 credentials to access images in my bucket?

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3

I am following the Heroku documentation for storing static files on S3 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3. I realize this doc has not been updated to explain how to create an IAM user, but I’ve done that and also created a policy for the bucket and a CORS doc. Then I added the env vars to Heroku as explained in the documentation, but for the IAM user. What I want to know, is how does Heroku know what to do with those env vars. Is the naming important? I’ve seen others name the env vars as S3_* instead of AWS_* like in the Heroku doc. I feel like there has to be a step missing, like, “then install this add-on which knows how to send along these env vars to S3 when requesting a static file”. Because my images aren’t showing up when I link to them in my Heroku app  using the public url provided when I click the object in S3 console

UPDATE

I was misled to think it was necessary to have an IAM user and corresponding credentials as env vars on Heroku in order to just serve static files from S3. @ceejayoz helped me realize this is not the case. All you need is a policy for the bucket that allows GetObject. You will see a Public badge on the bucket once you successfully do this, and then your files can be seen by the public via the Object URL (click on the file in the S3 console to see this). If I ever want to be able to upload files programmatically to my bucket, I will need a client (in my case the aws-sdk gem I believe) and all the other things I mentioned above (env vars, IAM user, CORS doc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's handled by the AWS SDK of the language of your choice.

For example, in PHP:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_environment.html

> To authenticate to Amazon Web Services, the SDK first checks for credentials in your environment variables. The SDK uses the getenv() function to look for the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` environment variables. These credentials are referred to as environment credentials.

Comment: ok, I just looked at the corresponding ruby documentation for the AWS SDK and saw mention of similarly named env vars (though no mention of  'S3_BUCKET_NAME' which the Heroku docs mention). So it appears my env vars are appropriately named but how can I know if my Heroku app is _using_ the AWS SKD? Is the presence of the env vars enough to let Heroku know to use the SDK? I really don't need to check a box or add an add-on somewhere to enable this?

Comment: @wetjosh You're responsible for the S3 integration. Your app won't use S3 unless you coded it to. If you're using Rails: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails

Comment: Let me ask you something @ceejayoz, if all I want to do is serve my website’s static files from S3, do I even need to deal with any of this env var/IAM user/SDK business?

Comment: @wetjosh As the doc you linked to indicates, "Static assets such as videos, PDFs, Javascript, CSS and image files can be manually uploaded to your S3 account using the command line or a graphical browser like the Amazon S3 console." No need for anything on Heroku's end for that.

Comment: well, I don’t think that document makes it very clear that you don’t need any of that stuff if all you want to do is serve static files. It led me to believe the opposite. And its weird that that document doesn’t mention the AWS **SDK** at all either (if I did want to do uploads). So I must have something wrong with my bucket policy or CORS or I’m not linking to the images correctly. Thank you for helping me narrow my problem down.

Comment: The SDKs are talked about in the "language-specific guides to handling uploads to S3" towards the bottom. If you need to handle user uploads, they're a good starting point (although many frameworks may have built-in support for this, too; Laravel does in the PHP world).